# Book about a telekinetic girl who is an elf?

Tags: story-identification, books

There's a girl, and she's in a school of some sort.

- There's a boy who helps her realize she has telekinesis and is an elf I think.
- I recall a council of elves.
- The girl gets adopted by some "elves" or just lives in a new room?
- There's some feathered dinosaurs and the boy is like "*surprised the dinosaurs have feathers?*" and the girl says "*no*" or something similar.?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Keeper_of_the_Lost_Cities/TZoyAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Exile/uEsdBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the cover art or any character or place names?

Comment: Telekinesis?  Or telepathy?  She can move objects with her mind, or she can read thoughts?  They are sometimes confused.

Answer (score 3):

This is *Keeper of the Lost Cities* by Shannon Messenger.

> Twelve-year-old Sophie has never quite fit into her life. She’s skipped multiple grades and doesn’t really connect with the older kids at school, but she’s not comfortable with her family, either. The reason? Sophie’s a Telepath, someone who can read minds. No one knows her secret—at least, that’s what she thinks…
>
> But the day Sophie meets Fitz, a mysterious (and adorable) boy, she learns she’s not alone. He’s a Telepath too, and it turns out the reason she has never felt at home is that, well…she isn’t. Fitz opens Sophie’s eyes to a shocking truth, and she is forced to leave behind her family for a new life in a place that is vastly different from what she has ever known.
>
> But Sophie still has secrets, and they’re buried deep in her memory for good reason: The answers are dangerous and in high-demand. What is her true identity, and why was she hidden among humans? The truth could mean life or death—and time is running out.
>
> [image]